# Losing String data when putting it into input value

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

i'm working on a jsp page and i want to put a String into an input text value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="adress" value=<%=adresse%>>
```

the problem is if 'adress'contains "abc efg" it only shows"abc" and the rest after the space is lost.

Comment: You are missing the quotes, however just to remind you this is generally a very brittle way to use values in JSP.

Comment: do you know a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the `""`

It must be like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="adress" value="<%=adresse%>">
```